# split a large file, add first line as file name

Tags: awk, sed, split, grep

I have large file given sample below. I would like to split it to multiple files, first line a name of the files example 'FP3SLUG00012600.txt'

i am able to split it to multiple starting at ">" but not able to name first line as file name.

in file:

```
>FP3SLUG00012600
ACCCTCCACGACACTCCTCAAGATCTCACCAAAATGCCCGGCAAGGTCAAGGCGTATGAG
>FP3SLUG00012602
ACCCTCCACGACACTCCTCAAGATCTCACCAAAATGCCCGGCAAGGTCAAGGCGTATGAG
>FP3SLUG00012603
ACCCTCCACGACACTCCTCAAGATCTCACCAAAATGCCCGGCAAGGTCAAGGCGTATGAG
>FP3SLUG00012604
ACCCTCCACGACACTCCTCAAGATCTCACCAAAATGCCCGGCAAGGTCAAGGCGTATGAG
```

output file needed with content in it

file1: FP3SLUG00012604.txt

```
>FP3SLUG00012604
ACCCTCCACGACACTCCTCAAGATCTCACCAAAATGCCCGGCAAGGTCAAGGCGTATGAG
```

file2:FP3SLUG00012603.txt

```
 >FP3SLUG00012603
ACCCTCCACGACACTCCTCAAGATCTCACCAAAATGCCCGGCAAGGTCAAGGCGTATGAG
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `awk` for split a multifasta file

```
awk '/^>/{filename=substr($1,2) ".txt"}{print > filename}' file.fasta
```

You get several files with a sequence in format fasta

Comment: prefect. worked as i needed. Thank you for the quick reply

Comment: @kapr0001 In this site, the best way to thanks someone that solved your problem is to accept his answer as a solution to your question.